# Sum of data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the sum of HTML5 data attributes in jquery?
Eg, when one and two are checked the value needs to be 15, when none are checked the value equals 0.

```
$('.price').html(parseInt($(this).attr('data-price')));
```

HTML:

```
<input class="checkbox" id="one" type="checkbox" checked data-link="111" data-price="10">one<br />
<input class="checkbox" id="two" type="checkbox" checked data-link="222" data-price="5">two<br />
<input class="checkbox" id="three" type="checkbox" checked data-link="333" data-price="2">three<br />
<a href="111,222,333">link</a>
<span class="price">17</span>
```

JavaScipt:

```
$('.checkbox').on("change", function() {
    var links = [];//array for links
    $('.checkbox').filter(":checked").each(function() {
        links.push($(this).attr('data-link'));//get links

        //sum of all price values of this into price
        $('.price').html(parseInt($(this).attr('data-price')));
    });

    $("a").attr("href", links.join(",")); // change link
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBJ3S/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FBJ3S/3/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to amend your code so that you keep a running total between each iteration of the loop. Try this:

```
$('.checkbox').on("change", function () {
    var links = []; //array for links
    var totalPrice = 0;

    $('.checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        links.push($(this).data('link')); //get links
        totalPrice += $(this).data('price');
    });

    $('.price').html(totalPrice);
    $("a").attr("href", links.join(",")); // change link
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FBJ3S/6/)

Note that it's also quicker to use `data()` instead of `attr('data-x')`

Comment: You don't need to use `parseInt` for numeric data attributes when you use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key): _"Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null)."_

Comment: But if you update the html by attr, we should use attr

Comment: @truongnm that's correct, but when dealing with `data` attributes you should both get and set with the `data()` method

Comment: Sure, but for me it's more reliable when I could see value change lol

Comment: There's no difference in reliability, but `attr()` is much slower.

Answer (score 2):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/DuyC3/)

```
$('.checkbox').on("change", function () {
    var links = [],
        sum = 0; //set sum initially to 0
    $('.checkbox').filter(":checked").each(function () {
        links.push($(this).attr('data-link'));
        //add prices of the checked check-boxes to sum
        sum += +$(this).attr('data-price'); // or +$(this).data('price');
    });
    $('.price').html(sum);
    $("a").attr("href", links.join(","));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/FBJ3S/8/)

I created new array for `data-price` and then added all elements in it.

```
    dataPrices.push($(this).attr('data-price'));//get links
    for (var i = 0; i< dataPrices.length; i++) {
        result += ary[i];
    }
    //sum of all price values of this into price
    $('.price').html(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.checkbox').on("change", function() {
    var links = [];//array for links
    var tempsum=0;
    $('.checkbox').filter(":checked").each(function() {
        links.push($(this).attr('data-link'));//get links

        //sum of all price values of this into price
        tempsum = parseInt(tempsum) + parseInt($(this).attr('data-price'))
    });
$('.price').html(tempsum);
    $("a").attr("href", links.join(",")); // change link

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FBJ3S/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FBJ3S/7/)

```
  $('.checkbox').on("change", function() {
    var links = [];//array for links
    var price = 0;
    $('.checkbox').each(function() {
        links.push($(this).attr('data-link'));//get links
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
           price = price + parseInt($(this).attr('data-price'));
        }
        //sum of all price values of this into price
        $('.price').html(price);
    });

    $("a").attr("href", links.join(",")); // change link

});
```